# Caret appear at end of placeholder onfocus when text-align is centered

Tags: javascript, html, css, center, placeholder

This isn't super important, I worked around it fairly easily by adding:

```
 onfocus="this.placeholder = '';" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Search...';"
```

However, just out of curiousity how would this be done?
Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vjLvssmp/

is there a way in CSS or would it require JS?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--EDIT

You can do it by using *text-indent* and *placeholder* selector.

```
.whitesearch {
  ...
  text-indent: 45px;
}

.whitesearch::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  text-indent: 0px;
}
```

Here's an example. https://jsfiddle.net/nonyok0q/3/

Comment: Hi thanks for your response! but I think you misunderstood the question, I want to keep the placeholder in place on focus, however I want the caret to appear at the end of the string "Search..." not in the center -Thanks

Comment: Hi, in this case you can play with text-indent. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nonyok0q/3/)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was after! didn't know that text-indent even existed! thank you!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.